# How to run a shell script upon user authentication (e.g. screen unlock)?

Tags: macos, script, login, unlock, authentication

I would like to specify a shell script (say one to send me an email) whenever a *given user is authenticated*, for example if prompted after sleep, fresh login or fast user switching.

PS: I found answers for running a script when the computer wakes from sleep and another for when a user logs into a fresh session, but that is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/159510/76470 :

I found [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/), a free tool that allows to run a script when the screen goes to sleep or wakes up.

After installing it, you can link a shell script that is run on one of the available events (which include *dim screen*, *wake up screen*, *computer sleep*, *wake up computer* and some more). From the shell script, I can run a command, or call an AppleScript that I want to run on these events.

Since my screen goes to sleep when I lock my computer, this is exactly what I was looking for.