# Run a program/script when the screen is locked or unlocked

Tags: macos, applescript, authentication

Is there a way to run a specified script or program when the screen is locked or unlocked? Ideally a bash function or an AppleScript.

Is there an event that I could subscribe to that would allow me to do that? Or an existing app that supports this?

Comment: For the lockscreen, there's notification sent which can be handled in Your Cocoa app. You'd need to listen to notificaiton called: "com.apple.screenIsLocked". Code: `[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"com.apple.screenIsLocked" object:nil];`

Comment: Is there a way to get a hold of this through AppleScript?

Comment: Sorry I don't know of Apple Script way of doing this. But creating Your own app for this task is not so difficult. Let me know if I can help.

Comment: As an addition notification sent when screen is unlocked is named: "com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some searching, I found [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/), a free tool that allows to run a script when the screen goes to sleep or wakes up.

After installing it, you can link a shell script that is run on one of the available events (which include *dim screen*, *wake up screen*, *computer sleep*, *wake up computer* and some more). From the shell script, I can run a command, or call an AppleScript that I want to run on these events.

Since my screen goes to sleep when I lock my computer, this is exactly what I was looking for.

You can see it in action here: https://github.com/nwinkler/sleepwatcher-lync-status

Comment: This program could be installed with `brew install sleepwatcher` you can find more information about configuration in plist files. The exact location `brew info sleepwatcher`. Default files are `~/.sleep` and `~/.wakeup`

Comment: I've a problem, it seems that if my mac locks before sleeping the script is not called. what parameters have you used?

Comment: Sorry, haven't used this in a while, TBH...

Comment: Under Monterey 12.5, I cannot get sleepwatcher to fire on wake/sleep. When I install it (brew install sleepwatcher) and then start it as a service (brew services start sleepwatcher or as global daemon with SUDO brew services start sleepwatcher) it will not fire on wakeup nor sleep. My .sleep and .wakeup scripts are OK and can be run manually. Also when I looked at the service within the 3rd party LaunchControl app, both instances of it are misconfigured which may mean the brew formula is broken. Also the sleepwatcher github has not been updated since 2014 so might not work with recent MacOS.

Comment: since Monterey update, each time I reboot, I get a dialog saying MacOs cant run unverified files, with 2 options, to uninstall sleepwatcher, or to cancel.

Answer (score 4):

EventScript has a few options that might work for you.  It's a neat little utility that can trigger .sh/applescript/automator workflows and trigger them on a host of different options.

Here's some screen locking/unlocking options: [image: EventScripts]

Check it out [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170812115839/http://mousedown.net/mouseware/EventScripts.html).

Comment: That looks pretty useful, thanks! It's $3.99 in the App Store.

Comment: I have issues with EventScript crashing silently now, so just keep an eye on it...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple script that I use when Karabiner fails on the lock screen. It turns the On Screen Keyboard on when the mac locks.

```
import Foundation

class ScreenLockObserver {
    init() {
        let dnc = DistributedNotificationCenter.default()

        // listen for screen lock
        let _ = dnc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("com.apple.screenIsLocked"), object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
            NSLog("Screen Locked")
            self.runShortcut(shortcutName: "Set Accessibility Keyboard On")
        }

        // listen for screen unlock
        let _ = dnc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"), object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
            NSLog("Screen Unlocked")
            self.runShortcut(shortcutName: "Set Accessibility Keyboard Off")
        }

        RunLoop.main.run()
    }

    private func runShortcut(shortcutName: String) {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
        task.arguments = ["-c", "shortcuts run '\(shortcutName)'"]
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
    }
}

let _ = ScreenLockObserver()
```

Save it to `mac-lock.swift` and run it with `swift mac-lock.swift`. Change the task.arguments to run a different command.

Comment: This was a great reminder that we can script stuff with Swift. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Info for future googlers landing here:

I got this working using [EventScripts](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/eventscripts/id525319418?l=en&mt=12).

I wanted my desk lamp, which is connected to a [TP-link smart plug](https://www.tp-link.com/ca/home-networking/smart-plug/hs105/) to turn on when I unlock my Mac, and to turn off when it locks.

I found [this bash script](https://github.com/branning/hs100) which can turn the smart plug on and off. (I don't have nmap installed, so I had to figure out the IP address of the smart plug by looking at my router's config screens, then supply the IP address to the `hs100.sh` script via the `-i` option.)

Then it was just a matter of writing two simple scripts for "on" and "off", to call `hs100.sh on` and `hs100.sh off`. Since EventScripts is on the Mac App Store, it can only run scripts in its own folder, so I put my two scripts there.

And voilà! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this free and OSS project [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/#how-do-i-install-it) (drop-in-app) and add this simple setup `init.lua` triggering:

- `${HOME}/.lock`
- `${HOME}/.unlock`

Note: used separate executable scripts for "portability" (but could have all-in `init.lua`).

```lua
    -- init.lua  
    local log = hs.logger.new("", "info")

    local function ok2str(ok)
        if ok then return "ok" else return "fail" end
    end

    hs.caffeinate.watcher.new(function(event)
        local eventName = hs.caffeinate.watcher[event]
        log.f("got caffeinate event:%s (id:%d)", eventName, event)
    
        local script

        if event == hs.caffeinate.watcher.screensDidLock then       
            script = "${HOME}/.lock"
        elseif event == hs.caffeinate.watcher.screensDidUnlock then
            script = "${HOME}/.unlock"
        else        
            log.f("ignored event:%s (id:%d)", eventName, event)
            return
        end
    
        local ok, st, n = os.execute(script)
        log.f("exec:%s -> %s, %s, %d", script, ok2str(ok), st, n)
    end
    ):start()
```

See docs at [Hammerspoon docs: hs.caffeinate.watcher](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.caffeinate.watcher.html)

Answer (score 0):

Run arbitrary script/executable on lock/unlock on a Mac.

1. Save this code<sup>1</sup> as `lockWatcher.swift`<sup>2</sup>:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation

class ScreenLockObserver {
    init() {
        let dnc = DistributedNotificationCenter.default()

        // listen for screen lock
        let _ = dnc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("com.apple.screenIsLocked"), object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
            NSLog("Screen Locked")
            self.runBashScript(path: "~/bin/logout.sh")
        }

        // listen for screen unlock
        let _ = dnc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"), object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
            NSLog("Screen Unlocked")
            self.runBashScript(path: "~/bin/login.sh")
        }

        RunLoop.main.run()
    }

    private func runBashScript(path: String) {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
        task.arguments = ["-c", path]
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
    }
}

let _ = ScreenLockObserver()
```

2. Make `lockWatcher.swift`<sup>2</sup> executable:

```bash
chmod +x lockWatcher.swift
```

3. Run `lockWatcher.swift`<sup>2</sup> on startup / login:

   1. Go to `Settings` -> `General` -> `Login Items`
   2. Click the `+` under the `Open at Login` list.
   3. And select the `lockWatcher.swift`<sup>2</sup> file.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This answer is *heavily* based upon [laktak](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/464720/93144)s answer.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Change the file name to what ever you want</sup>

Answer (score -2):

You can set it up like this:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /path/to/script
```

Comment: The name implies that this runs when you log in, not when you unlock the screen, though. Is that correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842016/launch-shell-script-on-login-in-mac-os-os-x/22872222#22872222 suggests that `LoginHook` is deprecated anyway. You can use `launchd` to run things at login, but that's not what this question is asking.